# How do I set a landing page URL in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, url, slug

I want my landing page the same as my home page. I want it not to have a "slug" or URL address after the site's name. So, for example, when you go to "www.example.com", I want that to be my home/landing page.

Right now, when I go to "example.com", I get a page I don't recognize and didn't design. To find my home page, I can click on *Home* in the navbar, but the "slug" is `?page_id=6`.

In the edit screen, I have clicked through "*Pages* ➞ *All Pages* ➞ *Home* ➞ *Quick Edit* ➞ *Slug*" multiple times. It always says that the slug for this page is `home`, but this is not how it appears on the web.

Furthermore, I don't want the slug for this page to be `home`, I want it to not have a slug at all. As I said above, I want the bare site name (example.com) to take me straight to the homepage.

Why does WordPress keep replacing "home" with `?page_id=6`? And why won't it allow me to remove the slug and make this page my landing page?

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, visit 'permalinks' under 'settings' in your dashboard. It shows many options how your page URL should look like instead of page=x.
Thereafter, read [this](https://en.support.wordpress.com/pages/front-page/) from WordPress site on how to declare which is your 'home' page when the site is accessed directly with site URL. That should resolve your problems.
Furthermore, generate and download a backup of your site using plugins like 'Duplicator' or other you maybe using so that you can always revert to previous status in case anything goes *very* wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that from settings page of wordpress.

1.Add any page and publish it.
2.Select the page from settings > Reading settings > Select page from dropdown

[image]